# Failed to fetch obteniendo datos desde json externo en react

Tags: reactjs

Me ocurre un problema, estoy extrayendo datos de un json, desde el que me dieron para el ejemplo funciona, pero cuando quiero usar uno mio me sale el siguiente error: `Failed to fetch`.
Asi es como lo tengo armado:

```
  const url =
    "http://api.football-api.com/2.0/competitions?Authorization=565ec012251f932ea4000001fa542ae9d994470e73fdb314a8a56d76";
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState();
  const fetchApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const responseJSON = await response.json();
    setTodos(responseJSON);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, []);
```

Dentro del `return`:

```
    {!todos
      ? "Cargando..."
      : todos.map((todo, index) => {
          return (
            <TableRow key={index}>
              <TableCell>{todo.name}</TableCell>
              {/*<TableCell>{todo.equipo}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.pts}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.pj}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.pg}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.pe}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.pp}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.gf}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.gc}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{todo.dif}</TableCell>*/}
            </TableRow>
          );
        })}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo. La url http://api.football-api.com/2.0/competitions?Authorization=565ec012251f932ea4000001fa542ae9d994470e73fdb314a8a56d76 es la que si funciona?

Comment: No, perdon, esa es un json de ejemplo, y no funciona, probe con otros json de ejemplo y algunos si funcionan, parece ser algo del Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Ese json esta en tu disco local? Si es asi ponlo en la carpeta public (si usas create react app) y en la url pon "/nombre de tu json". Fetch t permite hacer periciones a disco directamente